# How to insert user input data in an array in remix IDE using solidity?

Tags: arrays, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am a beginner learning solidity language. How can I insert the user input data in an array in solidity language. Following is the code I have coded so far with some errors.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract SampleContract{
    struct User{
      string name;
      uint age;
    }

   User[] users;
   uint i=0;

   constructor(uint _arrayLength)public{
      users.length = _arrayLength;
   }

   function addUsers(string _name, uint _age) public {
    uint i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        users.push(_name);
        users.push(_age);
    }
   }

   function getUser() public view returns (User[]) {
       return users;
   }
}
```

I get the following errors;

TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from string memory to struct MyContract.User storage ref requested. users.push(_name); ^---^

TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from uint256 to struct MyContract.User storage ref requested. users.push(_age); ^--^

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to push the whole Struct. In your code you are pushing one by one separately..

Correct code is..

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract SampleContract{
    
    
    struct User{
      string name;
      uint age;
    }

   User[] public users;
   
   //uint i=0;

   constructor(uint _arrayLength) public{
      users.length = _arrayLength;
   }

   function addUsers(string _name, uint _age) public {
    
        users.push(User(_name,_age))-1;
   }

   function getUser(uint i) public view returns (string, uint) {
       return (users[i].name, users[i].age);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I tried your code but when I add user an error message is displayed saying out of gas limit. I even increased the gas limit but either its same error or sometime taking time for transaction. Why is that so?

Comment: I actually corrected the array syntax according to your question. Now, I updated the answer and tested.

Comment: I dont know why where you using the loop. Its not needed here. whenever you push the new element the index will be automatically incremented. and please while  adding the name and age use proper syntax for strings and integer for example "Name", 20 like this. the gas error might be because you were not putting "" for string.